# How to create a specific-purpose command shell

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I'm working on one of my assignments and I can't seem to find any "how to" examples on how to go about it.

I need to develop a specific-purpose command shell to run on a Linux system that has at least 2 external and internal commands, e.g., pwd, ifconfig. The purpose of the shell is to present a limited set of functionality to a Linux system user. No language has been specified.

We weren't given any previous material that we could use so I'm lost on how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the "hint" given by the professor:

> "There are a number of different ways this assignment can be
>   completed. Some can involve a combination of aliasing, shell scripts,
>   using awk or modifying the tsh source."

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to know diffrence bettween internal and external command.
http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/internal-vs-external-linux-shell-commands

for example:
in ~/.bashrc

```
alias get_date "/tmp/script_1.sh"
alias current_date "/tmp/script_2.sh"
```

script_1.sh

```
time=$(current_date)
```

script_2.sh

```
date
```

and write to terminal:

```
get_date
```